# Managing multiple events for the same file change generated by pdflatex with a DispatchQueue

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am currently using a DispatchQueue and DispatchSourceFileSystemObject for tracking file changes on a pdf file which is generated by pdflatex. The problem i have is that when pdflatex generate the pdf, it sends several '.write' events and not only one. The job of the handler is to update the corresponding view where the pdf is displayed and i want to avoid to update several times the view with basically the same change(the handler is called every time an event of a specific flag is received). I want to call the handler only once and when the last '.write' event of the same pdf generation occur. For example if the pdflatex produce 10 '.write' events, the handler should be called only when the tenth event has been received.

I have tried to:

- check with a flag the current event received to ignore future event with the same flag, and then sleep for some seconds to wait until i receive all the '.write' events but this is not a solution, because depending of the pdf file to generate it could take different time for the process pdflatex to complete.
- get the modification date of the file, but with several '.write' sometime the date is the same for every '.write' and sometime it changes for 1 second etc.. so using the Date as a way to call the handler is not a good idea.

I am using a serial queue so the operation are not concurrent in the same queue. I would like, if possible, to continue to use the DisaptchQueue and only if there is no solution i would also appreciate a possible implementation with OperationQueue and Operation or BlockOperation.

Comment: I guess the number and type of events are variable. Is there any way to know which event is the last? If not, it sounds complicated. If you control the pdflatex call too, you can generate an additional file when pdflatex finishes (like "whatever-name.pdf.done") and use it as flag to know when the file is ready. In the process tracking the files look for those files to know when the pdf is available and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem in this way: every time i receive a '.write' event, i try to build a pdfDocument with his url, if the document is nil it means the pdflatex process is still sending '.write' events. In the last '.write' event i can successfully get a pdfDocument because the document has been completed.